# how to restart set live Wallpaper?

Tags: java, android, live-wallpaper

I upgraded example a live Wallpaper using gif animation. Link to an [example](http://dajver.blogspot.ru/2015/02/gif.html). This example uses only one animation. I did so in settings you could choose one of three animations. The problem is that when I set a Wallpaper and in settings, choose different animation after using the Wallpaper other animation is not applied. Activity with a new animation closes after apply. Is there a way to restart the set Wallpaper? I also recorded a video of this problem. The [video](https://youtu.be/5NTbiVayVXM) shows that the Wallpaper run. But only apply the ones that I used first.

Comment: Is this related to programming? Why did you tag this Java? From the way your question is written, it sounds like you want technical support for android live wallpapers. Stack Overflow is for Programming questions.

Comment: The source code to the project specified by the link. My code is the same it differs only that I change the name of an animation resource in the raw folder

Comment: Please include your code within the body of the post, as a minimal, complete, and verifiable example.

Comment: I think I incorrectly made the request and created a duplicate... Here is a similar question. But him and no answer..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32975711/how-do-i-restart-this-wallpaper-engine-after-settings-have-been-updated